# SPSS indicates that the .sav file is empty. Is there any way to recover the file from the Temp folder?

Tags: spss

I was just finishing my work. Had been working on this for 1 month, more than 100 questionnaires' data to enter on the database, there were only 3 left. My computer crashed, I turned it off and after I turned it on again, I opened SPSS and coudln't open the .sav file because of an error saying the file is empty (although its size is 68kb) and to try to open another file. I tried to recover the data through the journal file, through syntaxe, but I can't. Is there any way to recover the file from the Temp folder? I noticed that in the Temp folder there are some folders named like this: "pasw-cfe-1324076806484081348-tmp" which contain executable jar files inside. There are also some LCK files with the same names as those folders. After searching about PASW, I got the idea that it may be related to SPSS. Is there any way to open these folders/files? Also, I can send the file to anyone, in case this is needed.

Any help you can offer me will be truly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi Mariana, this question isn't really the subject matter of Stack Overflow.  I recommend you try asking this question over at Super User: https://superuser.com/  Good luck to you!

Comment: A little retroactive wisdom: (1) Always save your work in timed/numbered versions (eg myfile01.sav myfile02.sav etc') - new version for every chunk of work you've done. This way you always have a recent version to get back to if your current one if ruined for some reason. (2) use any kind of backup system. regularly. Especially with SPSS which doesn't have an autosave feature.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no there is no way to convert those temporary scratch file back into an SPSS Statistics system file (*.sav).  If you do not have backups of the file, perhaps in another format (*.sav, *.xlsx, *.csv, etc.) or stored as a table in a database, your only recourse will be to start over.

Answer (score -1):

I have an idea, you can do "system Restore"